# How to insert a new value into a sorted array (using two arrays); C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting

I am relatively new to C++, and currently writing a function that involves inputting a number of new value(s) into a sorted array. When the new value is put into the array, it needs to maintain it's sort in ascending order. This has to be done using two arrays (the original array, and a "destination" array that will contain the new, sorted value). I'm completely at a loss on how to go about this.

Everything that I have to do must be within the iostream and iomanip libraries.

This is all I have so far:

```
int insert_into_sorted (int source[], int source_len, int destination[], int new_elem){

    int offset = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= source_len; i++)
    {
        if (new_elem < source[i])
        {
            source[i] = destination[i + offset]; 
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't entirely know what I'm doing, at all. I have made a for loop, and an if statement within that for-loop.
When I execute the program, I input a test value. Based on what test value I enter, a certain new value is inputted.
EX: If I do test 1, it inputs a value of 15 within an array of 10,20. The 15 needs to go into the array of 10,20 while also being in ascending order.
However, my output contains:

Original array (10,20)
New array (-1,-1, 4255009);

I have tried rearranging statements, different return values, with slightly different outputs--but again, I'm so lost that I'm not sure what this is even doing in terms of how my program is running. Because it's a function and I cannot edit main, it's a bit difficult to test what is happening step-by-step.

Comment: You do it the same way you would on paper with a pen. Since the initial list is sorted, you copy all of the items from source list that are below the new item into the destination list. Then you place the new item at the current end of the destination list, and then return to copying the source list into the destination list.

Comment: Side note: When iterating over a container, a `<=` in the loop exit condition is almost always a bug. Eg. in `for (int i = 0; i <= source_len; i++)`, `i` has a range of 0 to `source_len`, including. If `source_len` is ten, that means the loop iterates 11 times and off the end of valid data in  `source`. So rule of thumb: If you see `<=` in a loop, stop and take a closer look. If the loop is iterating a container, verify the range, by hand if you have to.

Comment: Below was a terrible word to use above. In an ascending list the items below are larger. We want to copy items that are smaller, insert the new value, and then copy the items that are larger.

Comment: You could append all the new values to the end of the container, then sort the container.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that `destination` is large enough to contain the additional element.

You will probably want to first compare `new_elem` to each element of `source` before copying. If `source[i] > new_elem`, then you'll want to copy `new_elem` to `destination` instead of `source[i]` - this is to ensure that `new_elem` gets copied before an element larger than it and after an element smaller than it (which is how sorting works), and **set a flag to tell the function to copy the rest of the elements regularly** - that way, you don't keep recopying `new_elem` over and over again.

The code would probably look something like this (I'm only giving the pseudocode, not the actual code itself):

```
set `new_element_copied` to False
for each element in `source`:
   if the current element > `new_elem` and `new_element_copied` is not True:
      copy `new_elem` to `destination`
      copy current element to `destination`        //so as not to skip an element
      set `has_new_element_been_copied` to True
   else
      copy current element to `destination`
```

(the ` characters indicate variable names)

Also, make sure that when you're iterating over an array in C++, you use `<` not `<=`. Arrays are 0-indexed, so `arr[10]` would get the 11th element in `arr`.

**Edit**
If you don't end up copying `new_elem` in your for loop, make sure to copy it at the end by checking if `new_element_copied` is still False:

```
set `new_element_copied` to False
for each element in `source`:
   ...
if `new_element_copied` is False:      //indicates element was not copied
   copy `new_elem` to `destination`
```

**Edit 2**: Make sure to keep a seperate variable for the index of `destination`, as using the same index for both `source` and `destination` will screw you up